# A simple database

Tags: haskell, database

After failing miserably to get SQL to work with Haskell, I decided to try making my own system. It's fairly simple, but works well for simple jobs (I made it to handle highscores for a number guessing game). Its biggest issue is that the "tables" are only 1-dimensional currently, so it's quite limited in that regard.

Besides the obvious issue of it only being 1-dimensional, I'm looking for general feedback. Anything related to good/bad practices would be appreciated.

I'm also wondering about the tableIsInDB function. I need to do the pre-check for an empty list being passed to it (because if `any` receives an empty list, it will always output true), but that forces the second definition to have 2 parameters (otherwise I get a "functions definitions have a different number of arguments" error), which prevents it from being written point-free. This isn't a big deal, but I've noticed that functions being written point-free are generally preffered. Is there any way of writing it point-free if it has 2 definitions?

```
import Data.Binary
import Data.List
import System.Directory

type TableDatum = String
type TableName  = String
type TableData  = [TableDatum]
type Table      = (TableName,TableData)
type Database   = [Table]

type Path = String

loadDB :: Path -> IO Database
loadDB path = do
    fileExists <- doesFileExist path
    if fileExists
        then decodeFile path
    else return []

saveDB :: Path -> Database -> IO ()
saveDB path db = do
    let tempPath = (path ++ "Temp")
    encodeFile tempPath db
    renameFile tempPath path

tableName :: Table -> TableName
tableName = fst

tableData :: Table -> TableData
tableData = snd

tableIsInDB :: TableName -> Database -> Bool
tableIsInDB _ [] = False
tableIsInDB name db = any (== True) $ map (\table ->
    tableName table == name) db

getTableNames :: Database -> [TableName]
getTableNames = map fst

addTable :: TableName -> Database -> Database
addTable name = ((name,[]):)

addData :: TableDatum -> Table -> Table
addData dat (tName,tDat) = (tName,dat:tDat)

addDataTo :: TableName -> TableDatum -> Database -> Database
addDataTo name dat db
    | tableIsInDB name db = map (\table ->
        if tableName table == name
            then addData dat table
            else table) db
    | otherwise =
        addDataTo name dat (addTable name db)

getTestDB :: Database
getTestDB = 
    addTable "Third" . addTable "Second" $ addTable "First" []

getTable :: TableName -> Database -> Table
getTable _ [] = ([],[])
getTable name (cTable : rest)
    | tableName cTable == name = cTable
    | otherwise = getTable name rest

showTable :: Table -> String
showTable t = tableName t ++ ":\n" ++
    concatMap (\datum -> "\t" ++ datum ++ "\n") (tableData t)

showDB :: Database -> String
showDB db = concatMap showTable db

overwriteTable :: Table -> Database -> Database
overwriteTable _ [] = []
overwriteTable t db =
    map (\table ->  if tableName table == tableName t
                        then t
                        else table) db

sortTable :: Table -> Table
sortTable (tName,tData) = (tName,sort tData)

cutTableTo :: Int -> Table -> Table
cutTableTo limit (tName,tData) = (tName, take limit tData)

sortAndCutTableTo :: Int -> Table -> Table
sortAndCutTableTo limit = cutTableTo limit . sortTable
```

Comment: I guess for my question, I could use guards.

Comment: *"because if `any` receives an empty list, it will always output `True`"* -- this is not correct. `any id [] === False`. So you don't need empty list check.

Comment: @max taldykin Whoops. I was thinking of `all`. Scratch my second question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use more advanced data structures than plain list. As your `Database` is actually a map from `TableName` to `TableData` it is better to represent it as `Map`.

To use `Map` we need some imports (please be sure to import it *qualified*, otherwise some names may clash).

```
 import Data.Binary
 import Data.List
+import Data.Map (Map)
+import qualified Data.Map as Map
 import System.Directory
```

It is really nice that you provided domain-specific type aliases. This makes type signatures more readable and allows to easily change underlying data representation as in this case.

```
-type Database   = [Table]
+type Database   = Map TableName TableData
```

`Path` type is redundant as `Prelude` already provides `FilePath` alias to `String`.

```
-type Path = String
```

Fortunately `Data.Map` is instance of `Binary`, so `loadDB` and `saveDB` need only small changes.

```
-loadDB :: Path -> IO Database
+loadDB :: FilePath -> IO Database
 loadDB path = do
     fileExists <- doesFileExist path
     if fileExists
         then decodeFile path
-    else return []
+    else return Map.empty

-saveDB :: Path -> Database -> IO ()
+saveDB :: FilePath -> Database -> IO ()
```

Most of your DB-manipulating functions have twins in `Data.Map` module:

```
 tableIsInDB :: TableName -> Database -> Bool
 tableIsInDB = Map.member

 getTableNames :: Database -> [TableName]
 getTableNames = Map.keys

 addTable :: TableName -> Database -> Database
 addTable name = Map.insert name []

 addDataTo :: TableName -> TableDatum -> Database -> Database
 addDataTo name dat = Map.insertWith (++) name [dat]

 getTable :: TableName -> Database -> Table
 getTable name db = case Map.lookup name db of
   Nothing  -> ("",[])
   Just dat -> (name, dat)

 overwriteTable :: Table -> Database -> Database
 overwriteTable = uncurry Map.insert
```

Empty database can be represented as empty map.

```
 getTestDB :: Database
 getTestDB = 
-    addTable "Third" . addTable "Second" $ addTable "First" []
+    addTable "Third" . addTable "Second" $ addTable "First" Map.empty
```

Converting from `Map` database to the old list-based is easy with `Map.toList`:

```
 showDB :: Database -> String
-showDB db = concatMap showTable db
+showDB = concatMap showTable . Map.toList
```

Also have to note that I like your coding style: domain-specific type aliases and short functions with descriptive names make code easy to read.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't just use Map in retrospect. I loved Maps in c++ -_- (I haven't done much with them in Haskell though). And I had a mini-epiphany last night on a better way to set everything up (with column headers, and a SQL 'execute'-like syntax), so I'm not sure if a Map will still be applicable. If it does end up just being an association list, I might as well use Map; no point it reinventing the wheel. And thank you for your last point; that's a new habit. I'm finding that it definitely makes it easier to work with, even if it lengthens some names.

Comment: My plan isn't working as well as I would have hoped :/. `execute` (which takes a string command that's parsed) needs to have multiple return types, depending on what the command is, so I'm forced to use an ADT to represent all possible types; which will have to be dissected after to retrieve the actual result.

Comment: You can use continuation passing style interpreter, in that case command's return type will be encapsulated into continuation.

Comment: I've never heard of that technique before. It's called "continuous passing style" if I wanted to look it up?

Comment: Wow those look overly complicated. I think for this purpose, just deconstructing an ADT would be cleaner.